# AWS Cognito Token Expiring After 1 Hour

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm using the AWS Cognito JavaScript SDK to authorize and authenticate users in my React Native app.

I've managed to provide and store an IdentityId for users. Users who do not log in have access to part of my app as long as we authorize them with a confirmation because of Federated Identities / IAM. This all works well.

My question is, after an hour the token is expiring and their access is being limited because of it. What should be the process here? Do I retrieve new tokens, or do some sort of token refresh? What does that look like?

There is so much AWS Cognito documentation out there but I haven't really been able to find exactly what I need; and on top of, that I'm finding it really confusing to tell what I need for a successful Federated Identities / IAM authorization flow vs. what I need for a successful User Pool / log in flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have the credentials... and you called credentials.get() that first time... now on a timer after 55mins call credentials.refresh()... so you will have the credentials updated before they expire (do it every time you get a new credential... in 55mins refresh)

Comment: Wow, really? What about when the user closes the app for more than 55 minutes (or hours, or days, etc)? When they open it back up do I just call `credentials.refresh()` on load?

Comment: when open the app... call get() sending the token (you have the expire time, so you know if you can call refresh or if it is the first time (no expire time)), or is not needed because the expire time is later. I know is ugly...

Comment: Actually looking at my code now I'm not calling `credentials.get()` anywhere, but I am doing this: `var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity()` and then calling `cognitoidentity.getId()` to get the IdentityId, then calling `cognitoidentity.getCredentialsForIdentity()` to get the tokens & expiration. Do I still use `credentials.refresh()` for that?

Comment: are you using the credentials for lambda only? because you can create your own "token" and use a custom auth checking that token... and do whatever you want... like never expire the token

Comment: so... you are always calling get.... ok. then just call refresh before the hour timesout. if the user closes the app, when the app opens again, you call get again.

Comment: yep, if you already have the credentials... just call refresh

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much!